# /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string (makefile)

Tags: bash, makefile

```
prebuild-install:
    @rm -rf node_modules/
    @rm -rf package-lock.json
    @export GIT_BRANCH_NAME=$(git branch | sed --quiet 's/* \(.*\)/\1/p')
```

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'prebuild-install' failed
make: *** [prebuild-install] Error 2
```

I want to set environment variable by using this command

```
    @export GIT_BRANCH_NAME=$(git branch | sed --quiet 's/* \(.*\)/\1/p')
```

in `Makefile`, but get the error shown above. What is wrong in this command? When I take this line and execute it in terminal all works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Make treats `$` as introducing a *make* variable. You need to use `$$(...)` instead to pass a literal `$` to the shell for command substitution.

Also note that `make` executes each line in a new shell by default, so exporting variables has no effect on later commands. Usually you would use semicolons or backslash/newline continuations so commands execute with the desired variables in their environment.

```
 export VARIABLE=value; cmd_1; \
      cmd_2
```